# Status code without requiring webRequest permission?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension to fallback to Wayback Machine when a link fails.

webNavigation seems sufficient for the DNS-lookup case, but I don't see a way to detect link failure with only webNavigation in general.

For example, http://www.google.com/adasdasdasdasdasdasd is a 404 link - but I still get webNavigation onDOMContentLoaded and onCompleted, without indication of HTTP error (no onErrorOccurred is sent).

I was really hoping to avoid needing the webRequest permission with wide-open host patterns.  Is there a way to detect HTTP failure that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Send a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) `HEAD` request in `onBeforeNavigate` and analyze the response status code in `onreadystatechange` callback. If it's `404` then use `chrome.tabs.update` to change the tab url.

The drawback of sending an additional request for every page is insignificant since web pages usually generate a lot more requests while loading.

Comment: That's a nice workaround - I'd like to see if any additional suggestions come up.  It would still require wide-open host permissions -- if I need to take the shadow-XHR approach, then I think I might as well ask for webRequest permission as well.